# Not closing Odbc connection correctly

Tags: c#, odbc, dbase

I have a simple test Windows Forms Application. The first time I run it in VS everything works. If I immediately run it again it throws an exception about read protected memory at adapter.fill(ds); line. If I wait 5 or so minutes the app runs again. I would like some advice from the stackoverflow community on where I am being boneheaded. It is some connection timeout I guess. Code follows:

c#

```
    public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = @"Driver={Microsoft dBASE Driver (*.dbf)};DriverID=277;Dbq=x:\CMSBak\ISP;";

        var conn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);

        conn.Open(); // Open the connection

        string strQuery = "SELECT * FROM ISPINMAS";

        var adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(strQuery, conn);

        var ds = new DataSet();

        try
        {
            adapter.Fill(ds);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            conn.Close();
            throw;
        }

        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;

        conn.Close(); // That's it, now close the connection
    }
```

Comment: you really need to wrap that code in a `using(){}` also where are you accessing it again and or throwing the exception..? also put these 2 lines in your `try{}` block 
`DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
 dataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As usual a disposable object (`OdbcConnection`) should be disposed when you don't need it anymore.
The [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) will be very helpful in this scenario

```
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    using(OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open(); // Open the connection
        string strQuery = "SELECT * FROM ISPINMAS";
        var adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(strQuery, conn);
        adapter.Fill(ds);
    }
    // At this point the connection is closed and dispose has been called to 
    // free the resources used by the connection
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
    // No need to close the connection here
```

Also note that I have removed from your code the try/catch because you are not trying to handle anything there. You have just closed the connection, but the using statement will ensure that also in case of exceptions.

Comment: Tried putting the Using() in. The DataSet ds gets destroyed and wouldn't compile until I moved var ds = new DataSet(); before the using(). Also this did not fix the original error.

Comment: Yes the DataSet should be outside the using block.

Comment: Really difficult to say what is the cause of your error. Using should free the connection for the reuse but if it didn't fix the problem then we need to check other things. Did you compile for x86 Platform or AnyCPU?

Comment: x86 Platform but I had AnyCPU before.

Comment: Does anyone know how to change an Odbc connection to optimistic or pessimistic record locking? or if Odbc even supports a lockType?

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around. Use OledB instead and the Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 Provider. No more file lock worries.

```
    string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=X:\CMSBak\ISP;Extended Properties=dBASE IV;User ID=Admin;Password=;";
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    using(OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open(); // Open the connection
        string strQuery = "SELECT * FROM ISPINMAS";
        var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(strQuery, conn);
        adapter.Fill(ds);
    }
    // At this point the connection is closed and dispose has been called to 
    // free the resources used by the connection
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
    // No need to close the connection here
```

Comment: Ok, first this didn't totally solve my issue. However, if I shutdown VS2012 and restart I can run the program from the Visual Studio Debug environment. Thanks to @Steve for your effort.